# Installing F# NuGet packages on Xamarin for Mac OS X

Tags: xamarin, f#, package

I am used to [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) when developing in [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29).
I just bought a new [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac) and installed Xamarin fine as suggested.

I would like to install the [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) library called [Spreads](https://github.com/Spreads/Spreads).

It seems I failed to do it. I don't know if it’s my poor handling of this issue or if that library is not available for Mac OS X (I installed it OK on my laptop running on [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1) and Visual Studio 2015).

When I am in [Xamarin Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#Xamarin_Studio), if I click on *Project*,
I see the scrolling bar with "Update NuGet Packages" and "Restore NuGet Packages" but the button "Install NuGet Packages" is greyed and cannot be used.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a tutorial on how to install packages?

Bonus question: Where are the files of the solutions saved?

Comment: Can you post the error from the NuGet Package Console(If there is one)? Please also include a link to the NuGet package you referenced before.

Comment: The screenshot is hardly readable. It ought to be [cropped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to add a copy of [Spreads](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Spreads/) to an F# console application, using the latest Alpha version of Xamarin Studio (6.x) and [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) (4.4). These versions introduce far greater support of F#.

If you are attempting to add the package to a mobile project, such as iOS or Android, this will fail as Spreads does not offer a version that targets the mobile framework.

If you want to test version 6.x of Xamarin, I suggest upgrading to the Alpha channel via:

*[Change the Updates Channel in Visual Studio for Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/)*

Comment: i've followed the instructions, upgraded to Alpha channel. but the Add Nuget Packages is still grey like on the screenshot... how do I access it ?

Comment: Re *"Mono"*: Do you mean *[MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop)*?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First open the solution pad by going through menu *View* → *Pads* → *Solution*.

[Solution pad menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thod3.png)

Next, right-click on the "Packages" node that appears in your project

[Package menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyP5t.png)

The default location on disk for new projects is `~/Projects`.

Comment: thanks I managed to do it this way by myself actually, but thanks vm for your answer !!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of these actions?

- Open the Solution pad and right click on packages. Select "Add Packages..."
- Open the Solution pad and right click on the project. Select "Add -> Add Nuget Packages..."
- Open the Solution pad and right click on the solution. Select "Manage packages..."

[Xamarin article on Nuget support](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-nuget/)

Additionally, perhaps [this extension](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions/) would also help you?